# Unable to understand working of this type of return with 0 and -1

Tags: java, return, return-value, return-type

I am unable to understand the output how it works
i have added below

```
l1.add(54);``
l1.add(31);
l1.add(82);
l1.add(23);
l1.add(85);

Collections.sort(l1,new sorting());
public class sorting implements Comparator
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    int c =  (int) (o1);
    int d =  (int) (o2);
        return c>=d?0:-1;
    }
}
```

how the above return `c>=d?0:-1;` works.
what will be the value of 0 and -1 or 1
getting output as below

```
23
31
54
82
85
```

Comment: Your comparator is broken. It never returns a positive value.

Comment: ```c>=d?0:-1``` never returns the value 1. The current ternary operator can only return 2 values, and nesting ternaries to allow for more returns than 2 can start to get ugly really fast. I would recommend making an if-elseif-else statement to accommodate returning 3 values.

Comment: [javadoc of `compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)): "*a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second*" - and some more conditions that must be held

Comment: want to know the explanation of c>=d?0:-1

Comment: what does 0 return and what -1 returns

Comment: it got output as 23
31
54
82
85

Comment: but didnot understood logic of this part 0:-1

Comment: Why do you have to include the new Sorting() parameter with 
`Collections.sort(list,new Sorting())` ? You can just do a Collections.sort(list) and it will give you the same result. Your comparator returns a 0 when obj1 is greater than or equal to obj2 and returns a -1 when obj1 < obj2. It does not return a 1 ever.

Comment: We don't understand why whoever wrote that code wrote `c>=d?0:-1` either, because they should not have done it this way.

Comment: hi ashish/sweeper  i am new to java and i am learning comparator...i wanted ti know what value i will get when it returns 0

Comment: If you always return 0, the sort will do nothing.

Comment: @shmosel : Thank you that's what i wanted to know